# Reading data from NetworkStream when server closes immediately after sending

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, io

I'm serializing objects from a `Stream` with `BinaryReader`:

```
class MyClass
{
    public void Read(Stream stream)
    {
        BinaryReader reader = new Reader(stream);

        this.someField = reader.ReadSomething(); // IOException
    }
}
```

The problem in one case is that if I read from a `NetworkStream`, the server closes the connection immediately after sending the data. That results in an `IOException` ***("Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.")*** even before I read all the content on my side. How do I read that data? Isn't it buffered somewhere?

The protocol which I'm reading is *TLS* and the said situation happens if the server sends a fatal alert, and I want to read that alert, after which the connection should be immediately closed on both sides.

**Exception Message:**

```
System.IO.IOException
  Message=Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
  Source=System
  StackTrace:
       at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
       at System.IO.Stream.ReadByte()
       at System.IO.BinaryReader.ReadByte()
       at MyClass.Read(Stream stream)
    [...]
  InnerException: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException
       Message=An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
       Source=System
       ErrorCode=10054
       NativeErrorCode=10054
       StackTrace:
            at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
```

---

```
class Record
{
    public void Read(Stream stream)
    {
        BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(stream);

        byte contentType = reader.ReadByte();
        byte majorVer = reader.ReadByte();
        byte minorVer = reader.ReadByte();
        ushort payloadSize = reader.ReadUInt16();

        if(contentType == 21) // Alert
        {
            Alert alert = new Alert();
            alert.Read(stream);
        }
    }
}

class Alert
{
    public void Read(Stream stream)
    {
        BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(stream);

        byte level = reader.ReadByte(); // IOException
        byte desc = reader.ReadByte();
    }
}
```

Comment: what you describe is a fairly common pattern for a single request/response scenario; that shouldn't error

Answer (score 2):

It *shouldn't* be a problem. If the server really did just send all the data and then close the stream in an orderly manner, you *should* be able to get all the data it sent. You would see a problem if the connection were terminated in a less orderly manner, or dropped elsewhere, and possibly if you kept trying to read from it *after* it had already returned the fact that it had been closed.

What happens if you don't use `BinaryReader`, but just use the stream and do something like:

```
// Just log how much data there is...
byte[] buffer = new byte[8 * 1024];
int bytesRead;
while ((bytesRead = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine(bytesRead);
}
```

That *shouldn't* throw an `IOException` just due to the socket being closed gracefully... it should just exit the loop. If that works but your existing code throws, you need to check the assumptions you make in the reading code (which you haven't posted).

Comment: @MarcGravell and JonSkeet: I thought the same that it shoudln't be a problem, but using a sniffer clearly shows that the full message arrives at my end while BinaryReader throws that exception. I'm going to add more information to my question. The protocol is TLS and I'm encountering that situation when reading a fatal alert.

Comment: @rumbdolaf: That's why I'm suggesting removing `BinaryReader` from the equation - *just* dump the content of the stream to start with, to see how many bytes that gives you. If *that* throws an exception, you'll know that you really can't get the data, and will have to work on what's going on at a lower level. If that *does* return all the data, then it's presumably a problem with how you're using `BinaryReader`.

Comment: I'm currently using BinaryReaders ReadUInt32 etc. , going to try the "raw" read but have to prepare my current code first.

Comment: Ok I hate localized exception messages. In my language they dropped the important part of the message: "An existing connection was **forcibly** closed by the remote host." So Stream.Read has the same problem and throws the IOException. Is there any way I can still get that information? As I said, the sniffer sees all data.

Comment: @rumbdolaf: How much of the data was read by `Stream.Read` before the exception was thrown?

Comment: 5 byte (just the TLSPlaintext headers if we look at the TLS spec, not its payload)

Comment: Strange: it's 7 bytes with Stream.Read (which is the whole message), BinaryReader fails after the 5th byte.

Comment: @rumbdolaf: Okay, so this is where it's important to know exactly what you're doing with BinaryReader...

Answer (score 0):

> That results in an IOException ("Connection closed ... ")

That is more probably caused by *your side* closing the connection and then trying to read from it. Remote close should just result in one of the various ways the EOS condition is manifested in the API.

It would be a major mistake for the API to assume that an incoming TCP FIN meant that the connection was closed: it could have been a shutdown, with the other direction still operable.

Comment: No, my side is def. open. The full message as I edited is "Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host."

Comment: @rumbdolaf This demonstrates the complete pointlessness of posting the wrong error message. It just wastes everybody's time. Don't do that. And I can't see where you 'edited' anywhere.

Comment: Posting wrong message? The full exception log was in that question before your answer?

Comment: @rumbdolaf So why post 'IOException('Connection closed ...') at all?

Comment: Because thats the message translated back from my native language. 5 lines below is the correct one, and another 9 again. I'll edit that old one just to be sure ;-)

Comment: @rumbdolaf Really. Does the 'exception translated back from your native language' include '...'?

Comment: It dosn't include "forcibly". And as I'm asking this question and don't know where a solution is going I left it that way in my first version.

Comment: @rumbdolaf You're missing the point. You posted "...". The message did not contain "...". You mangled the message. Don't do that.